# Xposed hook to a system method

Tags: android, xposed

I'm using a custom ROM that added some things in a system method ([newApplication](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/8f6f1f43eeb0d7263b626978ee2c21d4053bf610/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java#972)) and I would like to replace its behaviour depending on the application passed as argument.

Is it possible to use Xposed Framework to hook a system method, particularly my method of interest:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation#newApplication(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.Context)
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/8f6f1f43eeb0d7263b626978ee2c21d4053bf610/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java#972

If yes, how can I do that? Because I can't figure out the package name I should be scoping the Xposed module to (using LSposed).

Many thanks.

Comment: As long as it is a Java method Xposed should be able to hook it. Just search for some Xposed examples and you will se how.

Comment: @Robert I'm actually stuck because I don't know which package name it should scope to. I'm using LSposed btw.

Comment: Then may be you should edit your question and describe in detail what you are trying to do. Your current question is useless as it does not contain any of the necessary information required to help you. And the two methods you mention are so generic that I don't see the point in hooking them.

Comment: @Robert my custom ROM added some things in this method (newApplication) and I would like to replace its behaviour depending on the application passed as argument.

Comment: That will be tricky, because Xposed can only hook a method to modify it's arguments and return value or replace a method. As long as the newApplication method can not be configured by parameters you only have the choice to call it or not to call it. So you would have to replace the method and re-implement everything it does in your Xposed hooking code.

Comment: @Robert, I actually solved the hooking issue. Even though the method is in the system framework, it is called when running each application. So the scope I had to specify is actually the application that's passed as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the method `newApplication` is in the system framework, it is called during runtime of each application.

So the Xposed scope I had to specify is actually the package name of the application that's passed as argument.